# How can I execute an ant target depending on the value of an environment variable?

Tags: if-statement, ant, environment-variables, target

I want to execute an ant script on two different computers. Depending on the name of the computer either one of the two targets should be executed. Following doesn't work:

```
<project name="import" default="all">
  <property environment="env"/>    
  <target name="staging" if="${env.COMPUTERNAME}='STG'">
    <echo>executed on staging</echo>
  </target>      
  <target name="production" if="${env.COMPUTERNAME}='PRD'">
    <echo>executed on production</echo>
  </target>      
  <target name="all" depends="staging,production" description="STG or PRD"/>
</project>
```

As I understood, "if" can only be used with property and it checks whether a property is set or not. But is there a way to to make a condition depending on the value of a property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest writing an "init" target that sets any conditions you need for later build steps, and also fails the build if certain required properties don't evaluate to what's expected.

For example:

```
<target name="all" depends="staging,production,init" />

<target name="staging" if="staging.environment" depends="init">
    <echo message="executed on staging" />
</target>

<target name="production" if="production.environment" depends="init">
    <echo message="executed on production" />
</target>

<target name="init">
    <condition property="staging.environment">
        <equals arg1="${env.COMPUTERNAME}" arg2="STG" />
    </condition>

    <condition property="production.environment">
        <equals arg1="${env.COMPUTERNAME}" arg2="PRD" />
    </condition>

    <fail message="Neither staging nor production environment detected">
        <condition>
            <not>
                <or>
                    <isset property="staging.environment" />
                    <isset property="production.environment" />
                </or>
            </not>
        </condition>
    </fail>
</target>
```

Comment: Hi, I would like have your answer rated at useful, but I am not allowed ;-). So, many thanks to you. This solution works fine for me. What I still don't understand, why "init" is called only once - is there an explanation why it is executed only once? I already read this in the manual, but didn't got it completly.

Comment: Glad I could help! Even if you don't have the ability to rate answers up or down, you should still be able to flag an answer to your own question as the accepted answer (it will mark it with a green check mark). Regarding the init target, upon execution, Ant forms a dependency tree from the dependencies named by your project's targets. If multiple targets share a dependency, that dependency is only run once. This is one reason why it's much safer and more efficient to use the `depends` attribute to control your build logic instead of the `antcall` task.